# Not sure where the segmentation fault lies during reading the data file in Fortran-based code (GNU Fortran Compiler )

Tags: fortran, codeblocks

```
  program main
  implicit none
  double precision,dimension(101):: p,q
  integer:: i,j
  write(*,*) "Hello World!"
  open(10,file='C:\Users\ACER\Desktop\test\results_analytical.dat',status='old',action='read')
  do i=1,101
    read(10,1) p(i),q(i)
  end do
  1 format(1f14.10,1f14.10,1f14.10)
  close(10)
  do j=1,10
    write(*,*) p(j),q(j)
  end do
  end program main
```

Output:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.

Backtrace for this error:
#0  ffffffff
```

The input data file is of the format as follows:

```
  0.0000000000  0.0000000000
  0.0050000000  0.0000000000
  0.0100000000  0.0000000000
  0.0150000000  0.0000000000
  0.0200000000  0.0000000000
  0.0250000000  0.0000000000
  0.0300000000  0.0000000000
  0.0350000000  0.0000000000
  0.0400000000  0.0000000000
  0.0450000000  0.0000000000
  0.0500000000  0.0000000000
  0.0550000000  0.0000000000
  0.0600000000  0.0000000000
  0.0650000000  0.0000000000
  0.0700000000  0.0000000000
  0.0750000000  0.0000000000
  0.0800000000  0.0000000000
  0.0850000000  0.0000000000
  0.0900000000  0.0000000000
  0.0950000000  0.0000000000
  0.1000000000  0.0000000000
  0.1050000000  0.0000000000
  0.1100000000  0.0000000000
  0.1150000000  0.0000000000
  0.1200000000  0.0000000000
  0.1250000000  0.0000000000
  0.1300000000  0.0000000000
  0.1350000000  0.0000000000
  0.1400000000  0.0000000000
  0.1450000000  0.0000000000
  0.1500000000  0.0000000000
  0.1550000000  0.0000000000
  0.1600000000  0.0000000000
  0.1650000000  0.0000000000
  0.1700000000  0.0000000000
  0.1750000000  0.0000000000
  0.1800000000  0.0000000000
  0.1850000000  0.0000000000
  0.1900000000  0.0000000000
  0.1950000000  0.0000000000
  0.2000000000  0.0000000000
  0.2050000000  0.0000000000
  0.2100000000  0.0000000000
  0.2150000000  0.0000000000
  0.2200000000  0.0000000000
  0.2250000000  0.0000000000
  0.2300000000  0.0000000000
  0.2350000000  0.0000000000
  0.2400000000  0.0000000000
  0.2450000000  0.0000000000
  0.2500000000  0.0000000000
  0.2550000000  0.0000000000
  0.2600000000  0.0000000000
  0.2650000000  0.0000000000
  0.2700000000  0.0000000000
  0.2750000000  0.0000014003
  0.2800000000  0.0000266683
  0.2850000000  0.0000507647
  0.2900000000  0.0000740585
  0.2950000000  0.0000970128
  0.3000000000  0.0001201538
  0.3050000000  0.0001440525
  0.3100000000  0.0001693017
  0.3150000000  0.0001964696
  0.3200000000  0.0002260195
  0.3250000000  0.0002582002
  0.3300000000  0.0002929297
  0.3350000000  0.0003297011
  0.3400000000  0.0003675440
  0.3450000000  0.0004050610
  0.3500000000  0.0004405502
  0.3550000000  0.0004722162
  0.3600000000  0.0004985024
  0.3650000000  0.0005186747
  0.3700000000  0.0005340630
  0.3750000000  0.0005510280
  0.3800000000  0.0005882177
  0.3850000000  0.0006938665
  0.3900000000  0.0009852838
  0.3950000000  0.0017346217
  0.4000000000  0.0035456488
  0.4050000000  0.0076987516
  0.4100000000  0.0167869702
  0.4150000000  0.0358201663
  0.4200000000  0.0740223065
  0.4250000000  0.1475576152
  0.4300000000  0.2833478844
  0.4350000000  0.5239305456
  0.4400000000  0.9329151358
  0.4450000000  1.6000355928
  0.4500000000  2.6441689288
  0.4550000000  4.2122092484
  0.4600000000  6.4716450046
  0.4650000000  9.5953727968
  0.4700000000 13.7388232959
  0.4750000000 19.0117014841
  0.4800000000 25.4490137475
  0.4850000000 32.9877526571
  0.4900000000 41.4558123539
  0.4950000000 50.5779426954
  0.5000000000 59.9999992531
```

Comment: Welcome. What is in the input file (maybe create a smaller file and adjust the counter here)? What is the result of the open statement? what is the result of the read statement.A bit strange to specify 3 fields in the formmat statement and only have 2 places to store information. Please try to compile with debug options (-g) and boundary checking options (by head -check all).

Comment: In gfortran the debug options are `-g -fcheck=all`. They should also be accessible from the Code::Blocks menu. However, the address in the backtrace is very strange. Are you able to compile and run a simple Hello world code?

Comment: Under your previous question I asked you to take the [tour] and use the proper formatting using  `\`\`\`` or using the buttons in the edit box. Please do that.

Comment: Change `read(10,1)` to `read(10,1,err=2)` and add the 3 lines `goto 3`, `2 stop 'whoops'`, and `3 continue` before `end program main`

Comment: All File I/O operation (`open`, `read`, `write`, and `close`) give you two optional arguments: `iostat` and `iomsg`. `iostat` is an integer that is 0 if no error happened, and `iomsg` is a string that returns a human readable message on what went wrong. Other than that, I recommend you use @VladimirF's `-g -fcheck=all` and maybe also `-fbacktrace`

Comment: @albert ...... this is how the data file has been created in the first place      
  0.0000000000  0.0000000000
  0.0050000000  0.0000000000
  0.0100000000  0.0000000000
  0.0150000000  0.0000000000
  0.0200000000  0.0000000000

Comment: @Vladimir F ..... hello world part is being displayed. I am sure that for some reason the code is not able to read the data which has 101*2 matrix format and each data is of the format 1f14.10.

Comment: Use [edit] to enter important information into the question. Do not use comments. Do use the formatting buttons.

Comment: As VladimirF already wrote add the important information in the question, especially input files, as in comment a.o. linefeed are lost.

Comment: @Vladimir F .... I have edited as per you asked. I am not sure if it is proper or not. This is the first time I am using this forum or even Codeblocks. So, I quite novice in that regard.

Comment: @BIDDU reread all comments and follow the suggestions as given (as far not yet executed) and report back.

Comment: @albert the issue remains the same, the "open" statement is not working. I have also tried saving and reusing the datafile in "*.cnv" format. Still the code is not working.

Comment: I didn't read anywhere before that the open statement is the problematic one. When you run your program in `C:\Users\ACER\Desktop\test\` just make the open statement: `open(10,file='results_analytical.dat',status='old',action='read')` when in another directory copy the file to the current directory, adjust the open statement and run. Please add your results to your question (as **Edit** at the end)

Comment: @albert ..I tried this out. However, I would like to point out that my code is running well in Force 2.0. It is just C::B where I'm stuck. I am not sure if this is a compiler issue. The output is the same as the one uploaded. The compiler can read my file but there is some issue with segmentation. I tried with a different type of file "*.cnv". It has still not worked. During the debugging process, the problem is shown at the line containing the "open" statement.

Comment: What is shown at the open statement during the debugging?

Comment: @albert   I had to reinstall the MinGW compiler along with C::B 17.12 to resolve the issue in another system. I am not sure if the aforementioned compiler works properly in AMD A10 processor of ACER laptop. My code was absolutely fine. All segmentation oriented issues have been resolved.